# How is ひたすら used here?

Tags: translation

Was browsing japanese pages when I came across this. http://www.hobidas.com/blog/rosso/mjb/archives/2011/02/post_765.html

The title was.

> ただひたすら純粋に美しい！　　であります

Doesn't ひたすら and 純粋 mean roughly the same thing? Are these two words commonly used together. From my little experience, I interpret this as "Intently pure in beauty!"

I also came across another example.

> ただひたすら純粋にレースしたくて仕方ない

Which from, from my assumption is "I can't help but purely want to race."

Can't just 純粋 be used here instead? What's the point of ひたすら?

Comment: Whenever I've seen ただ, ひたすら, and 純粋 together, I've always had the impression that they serve to reinforce eachother. So I would look at it as "Just pure beauty" or "Just totally beautiful", or something like that.

But, I'm not totally sure either, so following the answer with interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ひたすら means "to do only one thing".

純粋 means "pure".

ひたすら美しい is to do only one action of "feel".

In exact form, ひたすら美しい「と感じる」.

純粋に美しい is to feel "beauty" only, no other feeling.